# Pandas Dataframe not appending

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is what I need help with, specifically #3.

1. Import labelled data
2. Evaluate word for matches
3. Update labelled data with those words that are similar to 'labelled data'

I have a set of labeled data (say 100 rows) and I want to update it automatically, when a new word is similar to an existing row (i.e., SimilarityScore > 75%).

I start out by importing labelled data into two df. The first df (labelled_data) I use to calculate and store the similarity score and two columns (this is where I store similar text and associated score). The second df (dictionary_revised) is the dataframe that I want to append. Here is the code that I use to create those two df's.

```
#Read the labelled data
labelled_data = pd.read_csv('DictionaryV2.csv')
dictionary_revised = pd.read_csv('DictionaryV2.csv')

#Add two columns to labelled_data
labelled_data['SimilarText'] = ''
labelled_data['SimilarityScore'] = float()
```

Next, I calculate the similarity of Word A and Word B, updating labelled_data with SimilarTest and SimilarityScore. Works, here is what the output looks like:

```
   QueryText  Subjectmatter    DateAdded    SimilarText     SimilarityScore
2   hr        HR & Benefits     1/1/2020    support         0.771284
4   pay       HR & Benefits     1/1/2020    check           0.829261
```

Next, I created the following var to return only those scores > 75%.  Works

```
score = labelled_data['SimilarityScore'] > 0.75
```

Works, here is a sample output

```
    QueryText         Subjectmatter      DateAdded      SimilarText    SimilarityScore
0   store             Shopping           1/1/2020        retail         0.730492
1   performance       Career & Jobs      1/1/2020        connecting     0.743287
```

Next, I get the current date (as I want to know when the SimilarityScore was calculated)

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Finally, I attempt to append the dictionary_revised df set using the following.  But it is not working.  I have tried with 'results =' and without the 'results =' portion of the code.  Neither works.

```
for i in range(len(labelled_data[score])):  
    results = dictionary_revised.append({'QueryText': labelled_data['SimilarText'],
                            'Subjectmatter': labelled_data['Subjectmatter'],
                            'DateAdded': now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')},ignore_index=True)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The question is unclear, but it doesn't look like you need to iterate over matching rows from ```labelled_data```. Can't you just use ```concat```? If that won't work, then post a sample of what you think the final dataframe should look like.

Comment: Sorry the question is unclear. Here is what I wanted to do.
1. Import labelled data
2. Evaluate word formatches
3. Update labelled data with those words that are similar to 'labelled data'

Comment: Can you post a few lines of DictionaryV2.csv and the code for calculating similarity score?